# Навигация по папкам PHP

Tags: php

Вывел содержимое текущей папки , но не могу придумать как можно передвигаться по папкам, тоесть зайти во вложенную папку, потом еще в одну и так далее. Пытался в ссылку вставить вызов своей функции с таким параметром `$path/$file` , но так не отрабатывает. Подскажите как можно реализовать просто и правильно переход по папкам.

```
 function DirTable($path){
if(is_dir($path))
{
    if($d = opendir($path))
    {   
        while($file = readdir($d)){
            $mimeType = filetype($file);
            $fileTime = date("d/m/Y H:i:s.",filemtime($file));


            if(is_dir($file) && ($file!='.') && ($file!='..')){
                 echo(" <tr><td> <a href='#'> &#128194 $file</a></td><td>$fileTime</td><td>$mimeType</td><tr>  ");
            }
        }
    }
    if($d = opendir($path)){
        while ($file = readdir($d)) {
            $fileSize = filesize($file);
            $fileType = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);


            if(is_file($file)){
                echo("<tr><td> <a href='#'> &#128196 $file</a></td><td>$fileTime</td><td>$mimeType</td><td> $fileType </td><td>$fileSize</td><tr>");
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($d);
}
}
```

Comment: Вы зачем по 2 раза директорию читаете? Зы:запускайте рекурсию и будет вам хождения по папкам

Comment: Сначала читаю папки, потом файлы. Можете привести пример?

Comment: @ОлександрРуденко, дык все вместе и читайте, проверяя папка это или нет, в одном цикле

Comment: @DaemonHK смысл был видимо, чтобы сначала вывести папки, потом файлы

Comment: про рекурсию я погорячился, думал вам все дерево надо вывести. Очевидно путь к текущей папке в ссылке надо передавать как GET-параметр, например.

Comment: @teran не особо понимаю зачем мне GET запрос, путь к папке я получаю вот так ,и просто передаю параметром в свою функцию :`$path = getcwd();DirTable($path);`

Comment: @ОлександрРуденко а ссылки в таблице вы не на директории делаете, для перехода в них?

Comment: @teran так задумывалось, но я не знаю как это реализовать, может есть другой способ